# How to remove all duplicate elements from a list of lists in Python while also deleting the orignals

Tags: python, list, duplicates, set, intersection

I am trying to compare differences between the Fourier transforms of many different waveforms. The most prominent peaks (individual frequencies) from each transform are in individual lists. I would like to find common peaks/elements across all lists and delete them entirely. For example:

Input:

```
List1=[1,2,3,4,5,6,11]
List2=[2,3,7,8,9]
List3=[9,1,8,5,10,12]
ListofListIn=[List1,List2,List3]
```

Output:

```
List1=[4,6,11]
List2=[7]
List3=[10,12]
ListofListOut=[List1,List2,List3]
```

I need it to work with any number of any sized lists. I may have 50+ lists of varying size. I do not care about the order in individual lists as long as the elements of separate lists do not mix.

I have looked into `set.intersection` but my understanding is that it only compares one set to another and if i have a unknown number of lists It becomes quite difficult not to mention to do what I want every set will need to be intersected with every other set 50*50=2500 which is many intersections. Also `set.intersection` only deletes duplicates not the original.

I hope what I am trying to do makes sense to you python wizards out there. I have been banging my head against a brick wall here for several hours now, any assistance offered will be most appreciated.

Comment: Put all the elements into a `collections.Counter` and then filter out all elements whose count is greater than 1.  Much easier than trying to do N^2 intersections; it'll be linear with respect to the total number of elements.

Answer (score 1):

Using `collections.Counter`:

```
>>> List1=[1,2,3,4,5,6,11]
>>> List2=[2,3,7,8,9]
>>> List3=[9,1,8,5,10,12]
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> c = Counter(i for a in (List1, List2, List3) for i in a)
>>> [i for i in List1 if c[i] == 1]
[4, 6, 11]
>>> [i for i in List2 if c[i] == 1]
[7]
>>> [i for i in List3 if c[i] == 1]
[10, 12]
```

Comment: Very Impressive approach

Comment: This worked wonderfully I only had to make a couple small adjustments to work exactly as I wanted, you truly are a wise Sam.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [33]: List1=[1,2,3,4,5,6,11] 
    ...: List2=[2,3,7,8,9] 
    ...: List3=[9,1,8,5,10,12]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                

In [34]: counts = collections.Counter([*List1, *List2, *List3])                                                                                                                                                                                                               

In [35]: uniques = {c for c,count in counts.items() if count==1}                                                                                                                                                                                                              

In [36]: uniques                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
Out[36]: {4, 6, 7, 10, 11, 12}

In [37]: List1 = sorted(uniques.intersection(List1), key=List1.index)                                                                                                                                                                                                         

In [38]: List1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
Out[38]: [4, 6, 11]

In [39]: List2 = sorted(uniques.intersection(List2), key=List2.index)                                                                                                                                                                                                         

In [40]: List2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
Out[40]: [7]

In [41]: List3 = sorted(uniques.intersection(List3), key=List3.index)                                                                                                                                                                                                         

In [42]: List3                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
Out[42]: [10, 12]

In [43]: ListofListOut=[List1,List2,List3]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    

In [44]: ListofListOut                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
Out[44]: [[4, 6, 11], [7], [10, 12]]
```